# Localization files do not get generated in Windows Phone 8 project

Tags: c#, localization, windows-phone-8

I have a problem with Windows Phone 8 SDK. Accordign to MSDN, when I check additional languages in the project properties (WMAppManifest), new localization files should be automaticaly created. So when I check Slovakia (Slovak), a AppResources.sk-SK.resx should be generated next to AppResources.resx. This does not happend. When I create the file manualy (as I used to in WP7), it does not work.

I tried reinstalling the Windows Phone 8 SDK but it did not help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't rely on automatic resource file creation. Just check the new language in project properties and in app manifest. If you are developing app for WP7, then you have to edit the csproj file manually - add the supported language code into this tag:

```
<SupportedCultures>cs-CZ;de-DE;fr-FR;it-IT;es-ES;ru-RU;pt-PT;</SupportedCultures>
```

and then you just have to add the localized resource file named in your case AppResources.sk-SK.resx, next to the main resource file AppResources.resx.

Comment: I know how it is done. The problem is that it does not work for w WP8-only project.

Comment: What exactly is not working, localized strings are not loaded? Have you properly switched the emulator to target culture? Is the databinding of resource strings working properly?